# getting javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException in jsf 1.2 with richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, myfaces

I'm working on application that runs on (Apache myFaces) jsf 1.2 with richfaces 3. When i try to run my application from `<h:commandButton>` triggering an navigation case in faces-config.xml. But i'm getting below problem

```
SEVERE: View State cannot be reconstructed
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.decrypt(StateUtils.java:488)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.reconstruct(StateUtils.java:376)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.getSavedState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:187)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.getTreeStructureToRestore(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:151)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:219)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:515)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.restoreView(AjaxViewHandler.java:131)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.decrypt(StateUtils.java:481)
... 24 more
Mar 6, 2014 4:52:11 PM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils reconstruct
SEVERE: View State cannot be reconstructed
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.decrypt(StateUtils.java:488)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.reconstruct(StateUtils.java:376)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.getSavedState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:187)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.getComponentStateToRestore(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:163)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.restoreView(AjaxStateManager.java:222)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.restoreView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:515)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.restoreView(AjaxViewHandler.java:131)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils.decrypt(StateUtils.java:481)
... 24 more
Mar 6, 2014 4:52:11 PM javax.faces.webapp._ErrorPageWriter handleThrowable
SEVERE: An exception occurred
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /Register.jsfNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /Register.jsf
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:88)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is the problem i'm getting here???

My **faces-config.xml**

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
version="1.2">

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>payCloud</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.myApp.view.bean.SimpleLoginBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>cartUser</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.myApp.webCart.domain.CartUser</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/Login.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/UserDetails.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Register.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/Register.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>regUser</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/RegSuccess.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

And my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>PayCloud</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>

    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you doing anything to cause the session to expire either in your app or by waiting? View state is generally held in the session.

Comment: No but i'm using eclipse 3.5 and tomcat 6.0 so after few seconds tomcat throwing permGenSpace error following with above error

Comment: A permGenSpace error sounds like a memory shortage/leak. This might cause Tomcat to dump sessions.